# Python run a file as adminstrator

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, admin, popen

as the title says, I'm trying to figure out a way to run a file as an adminstrator. 
tried all of the answers I found online with no success... this one seems to be the closest to my needs -

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:userAdmin', 
'filepath.exe'], stdin=sp.PIPE)   
prog.stdin.write('password')
prog.communicate()
```

problem with the code above is that it just doesn't run the program if the file requires admin privilages... (no errors are showed).
tried to run same on a file which doesn't require admins privilage works fine.

help! :)

thanks for reading.

Comment: what are the file permissions ? are you using windows ?

Comment: file permissions full control, yes using windows. 

when I set chrome.exe to require admin it also does the same problem...

Comment: Did you try running it in a shell opened as an administrator?

Comment: Yes. same issue. if I try to open a file that doesn't require admins privilage it works great. 
changing the path to a file which does require admins privilage just doesn't open the file (without any errors)....

Comment: tried to open cmd as adminstrator and then open the program.py

trying to open the file gives an error - 
740: The requested operation requires elevation.